# Deleting Orphaned Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

In SharePoint Designer, I see that there is a workflow I'd like to delete.  When I select it and click Delete, I can tell it does something but the workflow never disappears.  If I log into the SharePoint site and go to the workflow settings, I don't see any workflows listed.  But it still appears in Designer.

How can I go about removing this workflow that appears to be orphaned?

Comment: are you seeing any workflow in sharepoint using the browser...check from here Lists > Site Workflows link. Tells us if their is any in progress workflow?

Comment: No workflows in progress.  Doesn't appear on the website, just in Designer and in SQL server.

Comment: try to clear the local cache C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft, close the designer and restart the Machine. Now try it, if you still seeing it...if possible share the screen

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in your 15 hive logs while deleting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a Site Collection Admin to see this folder in SP Designer, and click on All Files > Workflows > Select the Workflow > Delete. Press F5 when finished to make sure it deleted.

[image]

Comment: I'm using 2013, so it looks a little different, but yeah, that's how I go about trying to delete it.  It never gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thought, If certain operations fail to perform from UI / SPdesigner then go for powershell approach.

Refer this pnp powershell commnd to remove workflow definitions

```
Remove-PnPWorkflowDefinition
      -Identity <WorkflowDefinitionPipeBind>
                                  [-Web <WebPipeBind>]
                                  [-Connection <SPOnlineConnection>]
```

[Reference 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpworkflowdefinition?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Other reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4a4a8c3e-23cf-4334-bdf4-3db6e838f06d/deleting-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-from-powershell?forum=sharepointcustomization)